# frame add doesn't work to another java file

Tags: java, swing, jframe

test.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);

    }

}
```

My Other java File test2.java

```
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JButton Button = new JButton();
        frame.add(Button);

    }

}
```

am trying to call frame to test2.java

Comment: You need to extend `test` as in `public class test  extends JFrame{` and create an instance of `test2` before using it: `test frame = new test()`.

Comment: 1) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The reason you are getting this problem:

When you run a java application, the application's `main` function will be called. Therefore you should really only have one `main` function per application.

In your scenario you had 2 `main` functions. Think of this as 2 different applications. The following scenarios were happening:

- When you run the `Test` class, your application was creating a new `JFrame` object. That's pretty much it, it ended there. It had no idea that the `Test2` class existed.
- When you run the `Test2` class, your application was creating a new `JButton` object. *Although*, your `Test2` class had no reference to the frame variable (that is why you were getting an error). It didn't even know there was a `Test` class.

In order to fix this in your situation, try this:

**Test.java**

```
public class Test
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);

        // By passing the frame as a reference, the function
        // will be able to add the button to this frame.
        Test2.addButton(frame);
    }
}
```

**Test2.java**

```
public class Test2
{
    public static void addButton(JFrame frame)
    {
        JButton button = new JButton();
        frame.add(button);
    }
}
```

---

## A more [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) approach:

Here, I made a `Driver` class that would connect the `Test2` and `MyFrame` classes together.

**Driver.java**

```
public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
        Test2.addButton(frame);
    }
}
```

**MyFrame.java**

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame
{
    public MyFrame()
    {
        this.setSize(600, 600);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Test2.java**

```
public class Test2
{
    public static void addButton(JFrame frame)
    {
        JButton button = new JButton();
        frame.add(button);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks u That Worked

Comment: @Nick no problem, glad I can help :)

Answer (score -1):

I assume you're trying to add `Button` to the JFrame `frame` you created in `test` To do this, you'll need to make `frame` visible to what is essentially the global scope, as such:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class test {
    public static JFrame frame;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        test2.main(args)
    }
}
```

and then, to add the button in `test2`, you need to access `test` by name

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
public class test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JButton Button = new JButton();
        test.frame.add(Button);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it work @Dylan? Because I can see errors

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at test.main(test.java:7) Now i see my error :(

Comment: I don't get an error? The button didn't appear, but that's only because I needed to call `test2.main();`,which I added for clarity. Make sure you call `test2.main();` before `test.main();` is called